# C# : start up an application on specific time

Tags: c#, timer

i`d like to start an application on specific time on computer , how to do it in c# ? , simply i am working on application that the user will set a timer when the application has to run and do a specific task , i heard that in windows there is a tool that can be used to start an application on specific time .

Comment: It's called Windows Task Scheduler and is available under Administrative Tools by default.

Comment: Voting to close. This is more of a SuperUser question since the solution is using existing admin tools and requires no programming whatsoever. It's also been asked many times before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Windows has a built-in scheduler and .net has class to manipulate it programmatically.

You can find an example on [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the windows "at" command. You will need to run the command prompt with administration permissions to do this.

Here is the command help:

The AT command schedules commands and programs to run on a computer at
a specified time and date. The Schedule service must be running to use
the AT command.

AT [\computername] [ [id] [/DELETE] | /DELETE [/YES]]
AT [\computername] time [/INTERACTIVE]
    [ /EVERY:date[,...] | /NEXT:date[,...]] "command"

Comment: not sure why someone would vote this down, it's just another option the poster brought up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer.

it needs time in milliseconds to start.
You can calculate that by comparing the current time and the time you want your application to start at.

**and set resetAuto property of a timer according to you need**.